# How do you say “with” or “without” as in “I can't do that with you dying”?

Tags: grammaire, anglais, prépositions, conjonctions, subordonnées

How do you say "without -subject- -verb-" as in "I can't do that with you dying"?

Answer (score 2):

- "alors que" can do it too:

  > Je ne peux pas faire ça **alors que** tu es en train de mourir.

which means you can't do it because the guy you are talking to is dying.

- The negative form:

  > Je ne peux pas faire ça alors que tu **n'es pas** en train de mourir.

means that you need the guy you are talking to to be dying so you can do your stuff.

- If you use "sans" and the subjonctive:

  > Je ne peux pas faire ça **sans que tu ne sois** en train de mourir.

It means doing the thing and the guy not being dying are not compatible, for a reason or another.

- If you use "pendant":

  > Je ne peux pas faire ça **pendant que tu meurs**.

It means that while the guy is dying, you can't do it.

Comment: la magie du copier-coller ^^

Comment: Le dernier exemple, je me demande si c'est pendant que tu _meurs_ ou pendant que tu _te_ meurs... le premier serait davantage dans les instants qui précèdent la mort... ? Je n'en suis pas certain. Merci.

Comment: "se mourir" n'est plus usité à ma connaissance que dans un contexte littéraire. Cela dit, je peux me tromper.

Answer (score 1):

Using “with” or “without” in this fashion in English is just a way to bypass a conditional. The most likely way this would be expressed in French is by using explicit conditionals.

> Je ne peux pas faire ça si tu meurs.
> [I can't do it with you(r) dying.]
>
> Je ne peux pas faire ça si tu ne m'aides pas.
> [I can't do it without you(r) helping.]

Answer (score 0):

*with you dying.* => *tandis / pendant que tu meurs.*

Plus *mot à mot* : *avec toi mourant, avec toi en train de mourir.*

avec une négation (without), on emploie souvent le subjonctif (hypothétique):

*without them freaking out.* => *sans qu'ils deviennent dingues.*

=> *sans les rendre dingues.*

Comment: How do you say "I can't do that without them freaking out"?

Comment: @MarcoRubenAbuyuanLlanes  réponse augmentée

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina "réponse augmentée" sounds strange, you would better say "réponse complétée". "augmentée" has the meaning of "increased", does "increased answer" look odd ?

Comment: « Avec toi mourant » ce n'est pas du  français; « avec toi en train de mourir » non plus sauf si c'est deux compléments séparés.